# How to insert datetime value as dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL Server, I want to insert a datetime value as in the following format `dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` (`31-May-2019 11:06:37 PM`).

To do so, I have used the following code:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (GETDATE()), 106), ' ', '-') + ' ' + 
      LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 22), 11))
```

Output : 31-May-2019 11:06:37 PM

Column datatype : `datetime`

When I execute the following query, I get the result as I expect, but while using this in an insert statement, it stores the value as follows

```
2019-05-31 23:02:47.000
```

The format has changed.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Date, DateTime, and DateTime2 types do not have a format and are not stored as a formatted string. You only perceive a format because you are human so the default display shows you the value formatted in ISO8601 notation. The displayed format is not a concern of the persistence layer, it is a concern for the presentation layer where the value is rendered for a human to see it.

Comment: If is a datetime column, the format is server collation dependent. It will allways be a correct datetime value. Maybe you want to display it in a different format on the client side but that is total different subject.

Comment: Stored dates don't have format. They're stored as values that can be formatted depending on what's requested. datetime for example is stored as 2 integer values (one for the date and one for the time)

Comment: Formatting is applied by a client programm which you use to visualize data. Which one  are you using?

Comment: That's the standard format.

Comment: How to Get SQL Server Dates and Times Horribly Wrong https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you store it as datetime. Now you can display it in selects/reports as you want using `convert()`. Check this [cheatsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You can also use [`format()`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/):

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast('2019-05-31 23:02:47.000' as datetime), 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') as datetime
```

Comment: I'd post the official documentation instead of the cheatsheet as it does not add any value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: It's official documentation.